# Inserting same rows again when reloading page

Tags: refresh, href

I have this Add as Buddy href link

```
     <a href='#add' style='text-decoration:none;' class='common2 simple3'>Add as Buddy</a>
```

that insert new data in my Buddy table and shows a pop up message whenever it is clicked

```
     <div id="add" class="modalDialog">         
                <div>
                <?php 
                $sql="INSERT INTO BUDDY_REQUEST (requestor,requested, status)
                      VALUES($viewer,$viewed,'pending')";
                if (!mysqli_query($connection,$sql))
                {
                    die('Error: ' . mysqli_error($connection));
                }
                else                    
                    echo "<h4 style = 'margin-right:50%'>Your buddy request has been sent.</h4>                     
                    <div id='cancel_btn'>
                        <a href='#close' class='common simple2' style='text-decoration: none;'>Close</a>
                    </div>
                    <br>
                    <br>";
                ?>
                </div>
        </div>
```

however, i noticed that whenever i reload the page, it executes the < div id="add" class="modalDialog" > again even though i do not click the Add as Buddy link. So another same row is added to my table. What should i do so that it will not happen?

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming all of that code is in one file. If so, then your insert statement will run any time that page is compiled, regardless of whether or not the modal is visible to the end user.

You'll need to use ajax to make a request on the click event. The Ajax request will then call your php to execute the insert statement.

Comment: so what i need is an ajax that will call the div class?

Comment: To properly design this function of your app, take a look at Ajax requests and how they work. Your INSERT statement should be accessible via an entirely different URL which should be called when you really want to add a buddy.